# Using RaspberryPi 3 B as hotspot

Tags: raspbian, networking, hotspot

I am trying to use Raspberry Pi as hotspot device.
I am following this documentation:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md

I am not using ethernet eth0 to access the internet on the raspberry device. I am using wlan0 to access the internet. 
I have a USB wifi dongle and I want to use it for this purpose.

What changes I should do in the configuration as described in this documentation to achieve this?
The output of my ip addr command is like:

> ip addr

```
1. lo: ....
2. eth0: <NO-CARRIER,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3. wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/20 brd xxx.xxx.xx.xxx scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 xxxx::xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I want to add wlan1 where I will use the USB dongle to work as access point. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You asked what changes you should do in the configuration as described in the documentation. I have an alternative but simpler solution with systemd-networkd. Would this also be a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) you are referring to is a nicely written howto, I have used this approach many times and it works well.

If you have `wlan0` configured as a WiFi client to access the Internet, and use `wlan1` as your access point interface, you basically just replace every `wlan0` in the document by `wlan1`, and every `eth0` by `wlan0`.

Make sure `wlan1` gets the static IP in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
interface wlan1
    static ip_address=192.168.4.1/24
    nohook wpa_supplicant
```

And the DHCP service in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`:

```
interface=wlan1
dhcp-range=192.168.4.2,192.168.4.20,255.255.255.0,24h
```

And have hostapd listen on the right interface in `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`:

```
interface=wlan1
driver=nl80211
ssid=YourApNetworkName
... etc ...
```

You can read on all the hostapd configuration options at [kernel.org](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/hostapd).

Then, set the masquerading up on your Internet interface:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A  POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Make sure all services are started on boot and the masquerading rule is loaded. You can verify that by running

```
sudo iptables-save
```

Check if IP4 forwarding is enabled, you should see a `1` when doing:

```
sudo cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

One other helpful thing I learned from a [post on the raspberrypi.org forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=198946#p1244899) (Thank you [chispitas](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=249369)). Sometimes your USB dongles get renamed to something you don't expect. Adding this to a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/72-wlan-geo-dependent.rules` gives you predictable naming based on where you plug in your dongle:

```
#
# +---------------+
# | wlan1 | wlan2 |
# +-------+-------+
# | wlan3 | wlan4 |
# +---------------+ (RPI USB ports with position dependent device names for up to 4 optional wifi dongles)
# 
# | wlan0 | (onboard wifi)
#
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", SUBSYSTEMS=="sdio", KERNELS=="mmc1:0001:1", NAME="wlan0"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",  KERNELS=="1-1.2",       NAME="wlan1"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",  KERNELS=="1-1.4",       NAME="wlan2"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",  KERNELS=="1-1.3",       NAME="wlan3"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",  KERNELS=="1-1.5",       NAME="wlan4"
```